# Why do the Wirtinger derivatives follow the usual rules for derivatives?

Tags: complex-analysis

The operator defined as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ behaves like any derivative should and has all the same properties as well. But why is that? We didn't define it the usual way we defined partials of a function. Then why does it still behave normally?

Comment: It's a linear combination of classical partial derivatives.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes that gave me an intuition as to why. But why does that make it obvious that, say, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}(\bar z^2)=2\bar z$?

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}fg=f\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}+g\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{align*}
for complex-valued functions $f,g$, then it follows that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}fg=f\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}}+g\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}.
\end{align*}
With $f=u+iv,g=s+it$ for real-valued functions $u,v,s,t$, then $fg=(us-vt)+i(ut+vs)$, where $us-vt, ut+vs$ are real-valued functions, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}fg=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(us-vt)+i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(ut+vs),
\end{align*}
because this is how we define partial derivatives of complex-valued functions. On the other hand, for example,
\begin{align*}
f\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}&=(u+iv)\left(\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right)\\
&=u\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}-v\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}+i\left(u\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}+v\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}\right),
\end{align*}
then one can do brute force expansion to verify the equality.

For $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}(f+g)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}}$ should be easier.

For $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}(\overline{z}^{2})$, somehow the reasoning is like
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=\overline{\dfrac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial z}},
\end{align*}
in which case, for $f(z)=\overline{z}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}&=\overline{\dfrac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}}\\
&=\overline{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}z^{2}}\\
&=\overline{2z}\\
&=2\overline{z},
\end{align*}
and the fact that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}z^{2}=f'(z)
\end{align*}
is because $f$ is complex-differentiable. Note that, for a complex-differentiable $f$, one uses Cauchy-Riemann conditions to deduce that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=f'(z).
\end{align*}

Comment: But why is it that the derivative of a function of $\bar z$ is exactly what we would expect to get in case of a function of a real variable $x$?

Comment: I have explained the case that you are interested.

Comment: that is just one particular case. I want to know why it happens with all functions

Comment: I fail to see why it is true for all functions. Usually if the so called $f$ is complex-differentiable, then it goes through by the same reasoning.